# Unable to Register View Composer for Laravel Backpack Dashboard View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm attempting to register a View Composer for the Laravel Backpack libraries dashboard template, which is located at `resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/dashboard.blade.php` within my project.

I'm doing so via

```
View::composer(
   'vendor.backpack.base.dashboard', 'App\Http\View\Composers\DashboardComposer'
);
```

I know that the Composer is working correctly, because if I change the template to

```
View::composer(
   '*', 'App\Http\View\Composers\DashboardComposer'
);
```

the dashboard page loads correctly with the variable I'm setting in the composer.

I've tested to see if the view reference is correct by using

```
if (View::exists('vendor.backpack.base.dashboard')) {
    //
}
```

which returns successfully.

I'm registering my provider, `App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,` within the config as the very last provider.

Does anyone know why my composer won't attach to the dashboard view?

Comment: Is the variable you're trying to load not being added to the view or are you getting an error message?

Comment: I set a break point in the compose() method. When I use '*' the method gets called. When I reference the dashboard template it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backpack namespaces their views. You can try defining the composer for the namespaced version of the view:

```
View::composer('backpack::dashboard', ...);
```